# ps- ef grep process id values not coming properly when executed in a shell script

Tags: linux

I am trying to get the process id by grepping particular word.
Eg,
If I use the below command it is executed properly I am getting proper output through command line,

```
pgrep -f test-config/test-dev-properties.json
```

If use the same command through shell script and I passed the test-config/test-dev-properties as a command line argument and i placed this keyword in a text file.
During execution of shell script I have used as $1

Example:

```
processid=$(pgrep -f $1)
echo $processid
```

Even without passing as $1 i directly harcoded the value in shell script, even though I am getting below output

```
16744
23076
```

But here 23076 is my output..but it is printing extra values.
Even sometimes it's printing 3 values

Note: only one process running with the keyword I am trying to grep.

Not working ps command through shell script.

Comment: To debug this, run this from your shell script: `ps $(pgrep -f $1)`. This will print more info about the processes found by `pgrep`. Copy-paste the output to your question.

Comment: Always quote your variables unless you have a reason not to. Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script so you'll see a trace of all the commands.

Comment: The pattern is matching the argument to the shell script, so you're getting that process in the results.